# Check if a class element exists depending the class attribute using Xpath

Tags: xpath, jdom-2

I need to get the ratings(stars) of a particular company using Xpath .Below is the block of div element from which I need to decide if its a 5 star , 4 star , 3 star etc depending the class attribute

div class="star-rating star-rating-4 star-rating--medium" div

"star-rating star-rating-4 star-rating--medium" , if this is class with 4 star rating  I need to return 4 , 5 if its a 5 star rating and so on .One way I can do this is try to get Xpath of all variants(3,4,5 star rating) and whichever doesn't turn up as null return that .Is there any better way to achieve  this ?

Comment: The div element is as below                                                                                           
 <div class="star-rating star-rating-4 star-rating--medium">

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: java , and I am using Jdom2 for Xpath

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath 
**Based on the class of div:**

```
 //div[@class='star-rating star-rating-4 star-rating--medium']/substring(@class,string-length('star-rating star-rating-')+1,1)
```

**OutPut:** 4
[image]

**Based on index of the rating div:**

```
  //div[starts-with(@class,'star-rating star-rating-')][2]/substring(@class,string-length('star-rating star-rating-')+1,1)
```

This will return the rating of 2nd div with class name that starts with `star-rating star-rating-`
[image]